# Get the specific timestamp query on AWS Cloudwatch Logs Insights

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to get a specific timestamp so for example:

I need to query: December 31st, 2021 at 8:55AM

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 25
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filter by timestamp query on AWS Cloudwatch Logs Insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60707697/filter-by-timestamp-query-on-aws-cloudwatch-logs-insights)

Comment: The first answer in that question is the direct answer to your question ^

Answer (score 7):

Here are some screenshots of where to change it in the top right of the console as well.  First click on Custom:

[image]

then switch to Absolute and specify the exact start and end dates/times you want:
[image]

[Filter by timestamp query on AWS Cloudwatch Logs Insights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60707697/filter-by-timestamp-query-on-aws-cloudwatch-logs-insights) may address your question if you want to do it in the query.