# AWS Cloudwatch Log Insights filtering by timestamp in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, terraform-provider-aws, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

I am trying to create a monthly AWS CloudWatch Log Insights report using Terraform.  I want a relative filter by timestamp so that I am only getting the logs between (30 days ago) and (now).

Here is my resource:

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_query_definition" "audit_connections" {
  name            = "audit_connections"
  log_group_names = ["/aws/rds/instance/stuff"]
  query_string    = <<EOF
  fields @timestamp, @message
  | filter @message like /application_name/ and not (@message like /AUDIT/)
  (FILTER BY TIMESTAMP HERE)
  EOF
}
```

Similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60707697/filter-by-timestamp-query-on-aws-cloudwatch-logs-insights),
but the answer/solution was "just use the buttons at the top", whereas I need to do the timestamp in Terraform.  All examples I have seen have absolute between date and date, and I need mine to be relative as it's based on a monthly CRON.

Comment: This doesn't run a query. As far as I can tell, it only exists so that you can later retrieve the definition to populate a [StartQuery](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchLogs/latest/APIReference/API_StartQuery.html) API call (at least, I can't see anything that starts a query based on a definition). And `StartQuery` takes absolute start and stop timestamps, not a relative range, You'll need to use something like a Lambda to actually run the query.

Comment: I think you're right.  After more research, it appears Lambda is the way to go.  As someone new to DevOps, now I have to decide on which language to use.  Seems easy enough though, just have to hit the API and email the results.  Thanks!